# do not clear edittext values

Tags: android

am having three edittext and two buttons in my first activity. am giving the values for the first two edittext, and clicking the first button and moving to secondactivity. and again from that activity am passing a value to the first activity and saving it in the third edittext. But the values entered in the first and second edit text should not be cleared.

Comment: Okay, great. Where are you having a problem?

Comment: while returning from the second activity first two edittext values are cleared..

Comment: Have you tried to add the onResume() method in the first activity ?

Comment: ya tried.. even its not working

Comment: how you are returning back to your first activity .Are you calling activity or you are using finish method

Comment: What happens when you rotate the device without moving to second activity? Is the text still there?

Comment: ya while rotating the device text is there

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store the values in your first activity before your are navigating to other activity. Read the following article, [Retaining Values](https://sites.google.com/site/rajibkanungo/blog/openinganewscreenfromanexistingscreenandretainingvaluesinpreviousscreenwhenwegoback)